# What is the difference between EV-SSL certificates and Normal SSL certificates?

Tags: tls, certificates, http, chrome

Recently while looking at several banking URLs I can see the domain name with security certificate at address bar and normal locker security certificate at address bar. Have a look at the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Is it just an additional feature? What's the main difference between those two?

Comment: I think, that extended certificate is something like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first example is a normal SSL certificate meaning that it's a valid certificate issued by a trusted Certificate Authority, but there was no extended validation of the owner of the domain/site. This could mean that the certificate claims to be from Foo Inc. but the CA did not check that the person/entity applying for the certificate was indeed Foo Inc. when they issued the certificate.

The second example is that of a Extended Validation SSL Certificate. This type of certificate does extended validation in that the CA verifies the physical address and other details of Foo Inc. before issuing the certificate. In the end this just serves to give more assurance to the end user that the owner of the site/domain is indeed the company Foo Inc.

You can read more here: [How is EV-SSL different from SSL?](http://www.instantssl.com/https-tutorials/ev-ssl.html)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the lower bar indicates an

Extended Validation certificate, and the upper bar doesn't.

See [the support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?hl=en).